# Can the pre-requisite features/settings required to install a managed package be reduced over time?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, package, 2gp, second-generation-packaging

We have some managed package code that requires some features/settings (here shown in the `project-scratch-def.json` used for second generation packaging):

```
{
    ...
    "features": [
        ...
        "StateAndCountryPicklist",
        ...
    ],
    "settings": {
        ...
        "nameSettings": {
            "enableMiddleName": true
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

but want to make the package installable with or without those features/settings. On the code-side we know how to do that e.g. using dynamic SOQL. But before doing that work, I'd like to confirm that the features/settings can be reduced in future versions. Is that the case?